# When pasting a reshaped image, why does it lose its shape?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow with Python 3. I want to reshape a square image into a circle, then pasting it on another image.

My problem is, that the reshaping is done properly, and the image is made a circle, but when pasting it on the other image, it becomes a square again:

[image: Problem visualized]

That's my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    owms = Image.open("bg.jpg")
    asset = ctx.author.avatar_url_as(size = 128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    img=Image.open(data).convert("RGB")
    npImage=np.array(img)
    h,w=img.size
    alpha = Image.new('L', img.size,0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
    draw.pieslice([0,0,h,w],0,360,fill=255)
    npAlpha=np.array(alpha)
    npImage=np.dstack((npImage,npAlpha))
    pfp = Image.fromarray(npImage)
    pfp.save("outpfp.png")
    owms.paste(Image.fromarray(npImage), (101, 67))
    owms.save("outlvl.jpg")
    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("outpfp.png"))
    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("outlvl.jpg"))
```

(I have made it such that the output is both the circle shaped image and the intended original output.)

The solution I seek is the pasted image to be circle and not square like in the image above.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing left is to properly use the `mask` parameter in [`Image.paste`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste). Also, there's no need for this NumPy detour solely for adding the alpha channel. There's [`Image.putalpha`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putalpha) for that. Here's the minimized code (I left out the Discord stuff):

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

owms = Image.open('bg.jpg')
img = Image.open('get/your/avatar/here').resize((128, 128))
h, w = img.size
alpha = Image.new('L', img.size, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
draw.pieslice([0, 0, h, w], 0, 360, fill=255)
img.putalpha(alpha)
img.save('outpfp.png')
owms.paste(img, (101, 67), mask=img)
owms.save('outlvl.jpg')
```

I get the following outputs:

[image: outpfp]

[image: outlvl]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```